# Replace byte 10 by 10 10

Tags: c#, sequence

Hi I want to replace a byte[] where ever there is 10 by 10 10. here is my code.
if i have my data as "10 20 10 20 40 50 50 50 50 10 03" i want to replce it by 
"10 20 **10 10** 20 40 50 50 50 50 **10 10** 03" 
note: first byte is untouched 
plse follow my comment, my idea is to push the byte array to nxt position and add another 10.

```
 foreach (var b in command.ToBytes()) 
                {

                   // var c = b;
                    transmitBuffer[count++] = b;  data is formed here
                    addedbuffer[addall++] = b;     duplication is made
                }
                if (addedbuffer[0] == 16 && addedbuffer[1] == 32 || addedbuffer[50] == 16 && addedbuffer[51] == 03)           /
                    {
/condition on which to enter here
                        addedbuffer[0] = 0;  //making 1st and 2nd value as null
                        addedbuffer[1] = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < addedbuffer.Length; i++) //till length i will chk 
                        {
                            if (addedbuffer[i] == 10) //replace 10  by 10 10 
                                addedbuffer[i] = 1010; // error,
                        }




        }
```

Comment: Use a `List<byte>` instead of an array and call [`List<byte>.Insert()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: how do i set the position since 10 might appear any where ?

Comment: Loop through the list by index. Whenever there is a 10, insert another 10 right behind it (but don't insert another one after the newly inserted).

Comment: I'm sorry, I am bit lost, can U just alter my code and show me?

Comment: Adding a new item will change the count of the list, so you might want to go `for (int index = list.Count; index > 0; index--) { if (list[index] == 10) { list.Insert(index, 10); }}`.

Comment: Or `index > 1` to skip the very first item.

Answer (score 4):

You can't *insert* into *array* (you can do it with `List<T>`), so it looks that you have to create a *new* array; Linq solution:

```
  Byte[] source = new Byte[] {
    20, 10, 20, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 10, 03
  };

  var result = source
    .SelectMany((item, index) => 
       item == 10 && index != 0 ? new Byte[] { item, item } : new Byte[] { item })
    .ToArray();
```

However, using `List<Byte>` (in order just to insert 10's) instead of `Byte[]` is a better way out:

```
  List<Byte> list = List<Byte>() {
    20, 10, 20, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 10, 03
  };

  // In order not to read inserted 10's we loop backward 
  // i >= 1: 1st byte should be preserved as is even if its == 10
  for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 1; --i)
    if (list[i] == 10)
      list.Insert(i + 1, 10);
```

Comment: hi,  my data is stored in "private readonly byte[] transmitBuffer;" how do i assign this to new  array like in your solution ?

Comment: @Anil Gadiyar: just *assign*, i.e. `transmitBuffer = transmitBuffer.SelectMany(...);`

Answer (score 2):

It helps to think of sequences like arrays (`IEnumerable<T>` in C#) as things that can be transformed into new sequences. Much like numbers can be transformed when you send them into a function, sequences can be, too.

Consider if I have a function that is defined as `Add10If10(Byte b)`. It might looks like this:

```
public static Byte Add10If10(Byte b)
{
    if (b == 10)
    {
        return b + 10;
    }

    return b;
}
```

Numbers which go into this are transformed based on the condition, and come out either 10 larger or the same. The same can be done with sequences, you can take a sequence with some number of elements, and transform it so it has more elements. The result is a new sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<Byte> AddAdditional10If10(IEnumerable<Byte> values)
{
    foreach (var b in values)
    {
        if (b == 10)
        { 
            yield return 10;
        }

        yield return b;
    }
}
```

This function returns an additional 10 for every 10 it encounters. Now that you have the right sequence, you can change how it is stored by changing it to an array:

```
AddAdditional10If10(addedbuffer).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works via conversion to strings, using `String.Replace` and converting back:

```
byte[] source = new Byte[] { 20, 10, 20, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 10, 03 };

string[] strArr = Array.ConvertAll(source, b => b.ToString());
string[] replArr = String.Join(" ", strArr).Replace("10", "10 10").Split();

byte[] newArr = Array.ConvertAll(replArr, str => Byte.Parse(str));
```

Edit:

Another approach with LINQ - elements at first and last indexes and all elements not equal to 10 are unchanged, for all remaining `10`s it returns a sequence of 2 `10`s:

```
byte[] res = source.SelectMany((b, index) => index == 0 
                                             || index == source.Length - 1      
                                             || b != 10 ? 
                               Enumerable.Repeat(b, 1) : Enumerable.Repeat(b, 2))
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: i want to discard  first 2 byte and last 2 byte, i mean replacement must not happen in the first 2 and last 2 byte but rest everywhere it must ..even if there is 10 in the first byte it shud remain same

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly efficient way to do it (requires two passes over the input array, but does not require any resizing of the output array):

```
public static byte[] Replace10With1010ExcludingFirstByte(byte[] input)
{
    //  Count 10s excluding first byte.
    int count = input.Skip(1).Count(b => b == 10);

    // Create output array of appropriate size.
    byte[] result = new byte[input.Length +  count];

    // Copy input to output, duplicating all 10s that are not the first byte.

    result[0] = input[0];

    for (int i = 1, j = 1; i < input.Length; ++i, ++j)
    {
        result[j] = input[i];

        if (input[i] == 10)
            result[++j] = 10;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Call it with your original array, and use the returned array instead.

Test code (for use in a Console app):

```
byte[] input = {10, 20, 10, 20, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 10, 03};
var result = Replace10With1010ExcludingFirstByte(input);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

---

[EDIT] It seems from one of your comments to another answer that you also want to also exclude the last byte from conversion too.

If so, use this code instead:

```
public static byte[] Replace10With1010ExcludingFirstAndLastByte(byte[] input)
{
    //  Count 10s excluding first and last byte.
    int count = input.Skip(1).Take(input.Length-2).Count(b => b == 10);

    // Create output array of appropriate size.
    byte[] result = new byte[input.Length +  count];

    // Copy input to output, duplicating all 10s that are not the first byte.

    result[0] = input[0];

    for (int i = 1, j = 1; i < input.Length; ++i, ++j)
    {
        result[j] = input[i];

        if ((input[i] == 10) && (i != (input.Length-1)))
            result[++j] = 10;
    }

    return result;
}
```